# Pandas fails to read SAS as iterable

Tags: pandas

**UPDATE. This is a known bug - pandas.read_sas breaks if trying to read a SAS7bdat as an iterable.**

I receive an error while attempting pandas.read_sas on pandas 0.18.1 in Spyder 3.0.1, Windows 10.

I generated a simple dataset in SAS and saved in the SAS7bdat format:

```
data basic;
    do i=1 to 20;
        j=i**2;
        if mod(i,2) then type='Even';
        else type='Odd';
        output;
    end;
run;
```

We save this data to a directory.

The following code successfully imports the SAS dataset when run in Python:

```
import pandas
f=pandas.read_sas('basic.sas7bdat')
```

The following code fails:

```
import pandas
for chunk in pandas.read_sas('basic.sas7bdat', chunksize=1):
    pass
```

The error generated is

```
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 101, in __next__
    raise AbstractMethodError(self)

AbstractMethodError: This method must be defined in the concrete class of SAS7BDATReader
```

The same error is produced if I use the option iterable=True, or if I use both iterable= and chunksize= together.

Relevant documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sas.html

Sample SAS7bdat datasets: http://www.principlesofeconometrics.com/sas.htm.

Comment: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13654) about this

Comment: Thanks Max for the info.

Comment: pandas is free and I am not entitled to anything from its developers. But to encounter a bug in my first use attempt suggests to me that it is a second-rate product.

Comment: @user3348782 pandas is quite good, you were just unlucky